# Django-Rest-Framework csv module using paginated module

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework, export-to-csv

Hello I am using the `django-rest-framework-csv` module and I have followed the instructions to create a Paginated renderer using this code:

```
from rest_framework_csv.renderers import CSVRenderer

class PaginatedCSVRenderer (CSVRenderer):
    results_field = 'results'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        if not isinstance(data, list):
            data = data.get(self.results_field, [])
        return super(PaginatedCSVRenderer, self).render(data, media_type, renderer_context)
```

as I found it on their github site: [django-rest-framework-csv](https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv) . What I want the renderer to do is to return everything in the csv. Currently it only returns the current page. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its been a long time since the question was posted - but I had the same requirement.

I ended up overriding `get_page_size` method of my `PageNumberPagination`s custom implementation.

Here is what I did:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework_csv.renderers import CSVRenderer


class CustomPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 20
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 50

    def get_page_size(self, request):
    '''
    Set page size to unlimited (by returning None) when request format is CSV.
    '''
        # My version limits this only for admin users but feel free to change it.
        if request.user and request.user.is_staff:
            try:
                data_format = request.query_params[api_settings.URL_FORMAT_OVERRIDE]
                if data_format == CSVRenderer.format:
                    return None
            except (KeyError, ValueError):
                pass

        return super(CustomPageNumberPagination, self).get_page_size(request)
```

You can now use this as a pagination_class.

Example:

```
from rest_framework import generics


class SomeApi(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    
    permission_classes = ...
    filter_backends = ...
    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python csv module to convert the page and return in csv . I haven't tested it but i think it should work. I am assuming tab delimiter but you can change it.

```
import csv

class PaginatedCSVRenderer (CSVRenderer):
    results_field = 'results'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        if not isinstance(data, list):
            data = data.get(self.results_field, [])
        csv_input= super(PaginatedCSVRenderer, self).render(data, media_type, renderer_context)= csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rb"), delimiter = '\t')
        csv_output = csv.writer(csv_input)
        return csv_output
```

Comment: The renderer already returns CSV, but it only returns the records in the current page. I wanted to see if I could get the renderer to read all the pages and output all the records to csv.